# Promise return undefined AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I have a react-native app where I do some authentication.

I have the following code where I check if the token is not expired and its available.

```
export const isLogged = () => {

  AsyncStorage.getItem('@token')
    .then( token => {

      if (typeof token !== 'undefined') {

        if (tokenExpired(token)) {

          return false

        }

        return true

      }

      return false

    } )
    .catch( error => {

      return false

    } )

}
```

But in my code if I do:

```
let isUserLogged = isLogged()
console.log(isUserLogged) // -> returns undefined, but should return true because the token is there and its not expired.
```

Does anyone has some idea why its like this, I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: you have to chain up another `then` stage and do  your check in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to synchronously get a result that only becomes available asynchronously.

Change your code like this:

1. Add `return` before this call:

   ```
   AsyncStorage.getItem('@token')
   ```

   This will make your `isLogged` function return something: a promise
2. Use this promise in your main code:

   ```
   isLogged().then( isUserLogged => { 
       console.log(isUserLogged);
   });
   ```

The fact that your function `isLogged` returns a promise (when you return it, that is), is an example of [chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining).

Answer (score 1):

Your `isLogged` function is an asynchronous function, that is - it operates on values that might not be available to you in the exact moment of function execution, but delayed in time.

Since you are already operating on Promises here, you could just return the result of your `AsyncStorage` promise chain, and then attach additional handlers when invoking `isLogged()` function like this:

```
// inside your isLogged() function
return AsyncStorage.getItem('@token')
  .then(...)
  ... rest of your code unchanged ...

// when invoking isLogged()
isLogged().then((isLogged) => {
    console.log("is user logged: ", isLogged);
});
```

You should also read more about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in JavaScript.

Comment: thanks alot, is there a way to make this sync? and return from function directly?

Comment: No, the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) states that AsyncStore is (as the name would suggest already) an asynchronous store. If you want this to be synchronous, you have to find a replacement (but I don't know if there is any).